# How to create a whatsapp group with a single participant?

Tags: whatsapp

How can I create a group chat in the computer software WhatsApp with myself as the only participant?

This is useful because creating a new group is required in order to create an invite link for users you don't have in your contact list.

It seems that the computer software requires adding a second participant before allowing the creation of a group. Are there workarounds for this requirement?

Comment: This should be addressed to WhatsApp developers as a feature request.

Comment: One workaround is by adding Twilio's whatsapp test number and then immediately removing it